# Que lenguaje para el back usar? (bots de trading)

Tags: java, python, nodejs, reactjs

como estan?. Les cuento que no soy programador, solo he hecho un curso de java y algo de base de datos.. Lo que quiero hacer seria mas bien elegir un lenguaje para el back y ponerme a estudiar (ya que no cuento con mucho tiempo debo elegir un lenguaje sabiamente.. como lo de sabio me falta, entonces mejor les consulto a ustedes). El lenguaje a elegir es para al cabo de un tiempo aplicarlo para realizar un bot de trading de criptodivisas basado/que siga los parametros del RSI, este bot se deberia conectar a alguna plataforma como bitmex, bitfinex o kraken. Y la misma seria subida a una web/servidor para usarla de consola y desde alli comandarla. Entonces repito la consulta, que lenguaje creen que seria el mas apropiado? Yo tenia en mente estos tres lenguajes (les pongo el motivo por el que los tengo en mente):

1) Java. Por que hice un curso, y algo me acuerdo como para seguir y profundizar.

2) Node Js. Por que dentro de un mes comienzo un curso de node js(back) con react js(front).

3) Python. Por que se que se usa en algunos bots de trading.

Les agradezco los comentarios que puedan aportar, si pueden profundizar mas, como librerias y demas estaria genial.

Saludos!

Comment: Las preguntas basadas en opiniones terminan cerradas, por favor lee [ask]

Comment: Hola @pablob206 , puedes realizar este tipo de preguntas en el Meta: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/ , es el lugar indicado para opiniones como la que mencionas en tu pregunta.

Comment: No @CarMoreno de hecho meta es para dudas en el funcionamiento del sitio, si quiere apoyo con este tema el lugar es [chat] para opiniones

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que un bot de trading necesita consultar un API de un exchange o broker, procesar datos históricos y actuales de un precio, y luego tomar una decisión para operar.

**Por estas razones le recomiendo Python.**

Python tiene muchas bibliotecas y soporte para tratamiento de datos, consulta de API REST, y es un lenguage versatil, fácil de aprender y con una gran comunidad.
Además existen algunas plataformas que dan soporte de trading a Python. Esto lo puedes ver en artículos como este: https://blog.quantinsti.com/python-trading-library/

Esto es un ejemplo de un bot sencillo escrito en Python: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fpqzXgZjSqM

Esto es otro ejemplo con soporte de Shrimpy:
https://blog.shrimpy.io/blog/python-scripts-for-crypto-trading-bots

Comment: Por favor evita responde a preguntas basadas en opiniones pues estás terminan cerradas y tú aporte se perdería

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a la comunidad. Te invito a hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer [¿cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) para que tu respuesta sea bien recibida por parte de la comunidad. Obviamente esta respuesta es **SUBJETIVA** porque se basa en **tu opinión** y no una solución **OBJETIVA** al problema.

Answer (score 1):

No conozco uno que necesariamente se pueda incorporar a bitmex, bitfinex o kraken, pero si puedes cambiar de broker hay algunos muy sencillos:

ProRealTime  por ejemplo tiene su propio lenguaje interpretado y es tan sencillo que podrías aprenderlo en unos días 
https://www.prorealtime.com/es/pdf/probuilder.pdf

Por otra parte te recomendaría el propio lenguaje de metatrader el cual es el usado en muchos brokers y muy utilizado para divisas (este si es bastante mas complicado aunque orientado a objetos y similar a C++ ).

En resumen, existen ya bastantes software con sus propios lenguajes incorporados para hacer robots luego si tienes poco tiempo no creo que fuera eficiente aprender un lenguaje desde 0 con muchas más aplicaciones (como python)

Espero orientarte, un saludo!

Comment: Por favor evita responde a preguntas basadas en opiniones pues estás terminan cerradas y tú aporte se perdería